# What is mean by straight line (piece-wise fit) chart ? How to implement in MS chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart, linechart

I would like to implement the The Straight line (Piece-wise-fit) chart in MS Chart.

I have known points on X axis [Minimum = 1.4 and Maximum = 2.2]. I have put all these points on line chart.

Now the requirement is that How can I know the Points on X Axis [Minimum = 1.3 and Maximum = 2.3] with Straight line (Piece-wise-fit).

can anybody know about this chart then let me know How can I implement this chart.

Is it require to implement any algorithm or anything else ?

see attached screen which I have implemented yet.[image]

Comment: you want to perform piece-wise linear fit? (polynomial curve fit of order 1)? if so, how many segments do you want to split the data into?

Comment: see my attached screenshot. I am not familiar with Piece-wise fit. can you please provide more detail on this. and thanks for comments..

Comment: A piece-wise fit, is exactly what it sounds like, you divide your data into segments (or pieces); values 1 to 10, values 11 to 20 and so on... and then for each segment your perform a linear fit. 
The result will look something like this:
http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2012/03/02/piecewise-linear-curve-fitting/
Notice how after every "bend" the line is straight until the next "bend". 

Obviously, if you do not split the data into segments, you have just "one segment" and a single straight line of best fit,
like so: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Linear_regression.svg

Comment: It all depends on how you want to model the data. Dont split the data into segments if the nature of what created the data did not have that alternating characteristic (a changing derivative). 

If your data did not have a changing derivate but just a steady increase in value, then a single line of best fit is the only way to model the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have correct the problem by myself.

I have used MS Chart Best fit Curve (Spline) in Chart Type.